# zsh: using different WORDCHARS for kill-word and forward-word / backward-word

Tags: zsh

When I don't include `/` in `WORDCHARS`, ie:

```
WORDCHARS='~!#$%^&*(){}[]<>?.+;-'
```

then `kill-word` works as desired: with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, I can delete parts of filesystem paths (stopping at each `/`).

But when using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, I would like to have different behaviour: I don't want the cursor to stop at each `/`. I want to skip the whole path as one word.

Can I use different `WORDCHARS` only for `forward-word` and `backward-word` ?

Comment: I think that this is exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587656/9778755 It does what you describe without setting `WORDCHARS`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could `bind` the `vi-{back,for}ward-blank-word` widgets to <kbd>Ctrl+{left,right}</kbd>:

```
bindkey $'\E[1;5D' vi-backward-blank-word
bindkey $'\E[1;5C' vi-forward-blank-word
```

or redefine the `{back,for}ward-word` widgets to use a different `WORDCHARS` (so it would affect other bindings (like <kbd>Alt+{B,F}</kbd>) that use those widgets):

```
WORDCHARS='~!#$%^&*(){}[]<>?.+;-'
MOTION_WORDCHARS='~!#$%^&*(){}[]<>?.+;-/'

''{back,for}ward-word() WORDCHARS=$MOTION_WORDCHARS zle .$WIDGET
zle -N backward-word
zle -N forward-word
```

See also [`info zsh select-word-style`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-select_002dword_002dstyle) for a framework to dynamically select *word styles*.

You can also use it to select different word styles for different widgets like:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
zle -N select-word-style
bindkey '\ez' select-word-style

WORDCHARS='~!#$%^&*(){}[]<>?.+;-' # for the "normal" style
select-word-style normal
zstyle ':zle:*ward-word' word-style space
zstyle ':zle:backward-kill-word' word-style space
```

You'd get the "space"-based word style for the `*ward-word` and `backward-kill-word` widgets and whatever is selected by <kbd>Alt+Z</kbd>, initially "normal", `$WORDCHARS`-based word style for the other word widgets.

Comment: `vi-{back,for}ward-blank-word` is the perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: I would like `Ctrl`+`w` to behave same as `Ctrl`+`Right`, (ie not stop at `/`). I tried adding `bindkey '^W' vi-backward-kill-word`, but that did not help.

Comment: In other words, `vi-backward-kill-word` behaves same as `backward-kill-word`.

Comment: @400theCat, yes there's no `vi-backward-kill-blank-word` as there's no such concept in `vi` (as opposed to the `B`/`E`/`W` motions in `vi`). You can use the second approach.

Comment: can I define `MOTION_WORDCHARS` to contain every character except space ? I could enumerate all ASCII characters, but what will happen if some unicode character appears on the commandline /

Comment: @400theCat, when `WORDCHARs` is unset, it defaults to blank delimited words, so you can do `local WORDCHARS; unset WORDCHARS` in the widgets you want to behave that way. `backward-word forward-word backward-kill-word() { local WORDCHARS; unset WORDCHARS; zle .$WIDGET; }`

Comment: @400theCat, see edit for how you can also leverage `select-word-style` for what you need here.